# How show that the discrete random variable converges in mean square?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Given a discrete random variable $X_n=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$
with $p = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2n} & 1-\frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{2n}
\end{pmatrix}$
where $E(X_n)=0$ and $Var(X_n)=\frac{1}{n}$ and $X_n$ converges to zero. Show that $X_n$ converges in mean square.

Wikipedia says that $X_n$ converges in mean square to $X$ if $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(|X_n-X|^2) = 0$$

But now I don't know what this $X$ is, does it need to be told by the task what it is exactly? Or is this $X$ always $X = E(X_n)$ ?

I assume this is the case, so then I can conclude that it's the same as saying
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Var(X_n) = 0$$

We know that $Var(X_n) = \frac{1}{n}$ thus $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$$

Is it correct like that?

Comment: What you have written makes sense if $X$ is a constant (as it is in this particular question), but $X$ can be a non-constant random variable and still have convergence in mean-square

Comment: Your reasoning is correct but the way you write $X=E(X_n)$ makes me unsure on whether you understand it. The $X$ you define cannot depend on $n$ (here it turns out $E(X_n)=0$ for all $n$ so it makes sense to consider $X=0$, but that's kind of a special case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $X$ is a random variable towards which your random variables $X_n$ converges. If you are not given $X$ then you have to try to think of a random variable towards which your series of random variables converges. In your particular case $X$ should be the random variable which is $0$ with probability $1$.

Then we have:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb E\left((X_n - X)^2\right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E\left(X_n^2\right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0 \cdot \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + 1\cdot \frac{1}{n} = 0 $$

This proves that $X_n$ converges towards the random variable which is always $0$.

Comment: Understood, thank you everyone! :)